# SqlBulkCopy start index?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I have a table that i want to copy to another table using SqlBulkCopy, but in my destination table i have an ID. 
So like this:

Source table

```
variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4
```

Destination table

```
ID, variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4
```

How can i make make sure that sqlbulkcopy starts at index 1 in my destination table?
The only work around i've found is that adding ID as the last variable, like this:

Destination table(2)

```
variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, ID
```

**EDIT**
As seen in my answer to Christos, ID is already set as IDENTITY(1,1).

Comment: So what's wrong? You get an error? Your ID values are not correct?

Comment: Ye, it says that my attributes doesn't match. Since it starts with the ID in my destination table.

Answer (score 0):

If the schemas in source and destination are different you need to provide [column mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmappingcollection(v=vs.110).aspx). If mappings are not defined then columns are mapped implicitly based on ordinal position. You can add the mappings like this:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
{
  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "destination_table";

  bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("variable1", "variable1");
  bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("variable2", "variable2");
  bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("variable3", "variable3");

  // etc.
```

This way the ID column in destination will be ignored and the default value (identity) will be used to populate it.